# Allow comments only for author of the node and certain role

Tags: comments, users

I'm using Drupal 7. It is possible to disable the comment form for a specific node type for authenticated users? What hooks should I use if I want to allow only the author of the node and the administrator to post comments. The normal users (authenticated role) should only read them.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably unset the comment form using `hook_form_alter` on the basis on certain condition:

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ( $form_id == 'comment_form') {
    global $user;
    if (!user_access('administer nodes') {
      // Form alter here to unset comment form
      unset($form);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: unset($form) it´s not working. I´ll give it another try and I´ll post the result.

Comment: `$form['#access'] = FALSE;` might be a bit more bulletproof...

Comment: @SergiuPopa You could try to follow Clive's recommendation, or you could just go on by `unset`ing individual form elements of the comment form. See the comment module for the individual fields on the form.

Comment: Finally I used hook_form_FORM_ID_alter with $form['#access'] = FALSE; Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Comment Access](http://drupal.org/project/commentaccess) module.

> Comment Access allows your users to control the comments on their posts. It adds permissions to administer, approve, and delete comments on nodes they create without granting full comment administration access.   Permissions are granted by node type, so it's a great way to allow your users to manage comments on their own blogs.
>
> #### Features
>
> - Adds permissions to:
>
>   - Administer comments on own content (for each content type)
>   - Delete comments on own content (for each content type)
>   - Approve comments on own content (for each content type) User
> - Option for e-mail notifications on comments needing approval site
> - Administrators can set a custom comment approval message and e-mail
> - Unapproved comments are left unpublished, so site administrators can still work with them as normal

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't have the permission I want: Post comment if user is author. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

If by *administrator* you mean the user whose ID is 1, I would use the following code.

```
/*
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $uid = $user->uid;
  if (($uid !== 1 && !isset($form['#node']) || ($uid !== 1 && $form['#node']->uid == $uid)) {
    $form['access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

If by *administrator* you mean the users who have the permission to administer comments, I would use use the following code.

```
/*
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $permission = user_access('administer permissions');
  if ((!$permission && !isset($form['#node']) || (!$permission && $form['#node']->uid == $user->uid)) {
    $form['access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

If by *administrator* you mean a user with a different permission, replace `'administer permissions'` with the permission you want to check.

In any case:

- Setting `$form['access']` to `FALSE` is better to unset `$form`, which would throw many warnings because of module accessing a `NULL` value as it would be an array
- Implementing `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` is better than implementing `hook_form_alter()` as the latter is invoked for every form, while the first is invoked only of a form type